# Why is chop being ignored?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

If I use

```
Chop[10^-4, 10^-3]
```

then I'd expect the output to be zero. However, this is not the case. There is of course a very easy workaround since I can define my own "chop"

```
chop[x_,dx_] := If[Abs[x] < dx, 0, x]
```

but why is the innate version failing?

Comment: Please see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J7qs8.png) and the docs of `Chop`: _"Chop works on both Real and Complex numbers."_ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation states that `Chop`

> replaces **approximate** real numbers in *expr* that are close to zero by
>   the exact integer 0.

but you number is not approximate! Try

```
Chop[10^-4 // N, 10^-3]
```

It might be enlightening to evaluate `10^-4 // FullForm` to see how `10^-4` is represented in *Mathematica*.